# How to select dynamically added control through jquery OR How to generate dynamic ID in jquery OR suggest dynamic selector of this jquery

Tags: jquery, selector

How to get

I have created one user control and it is loaded dynamically mulitple times on single page.
My User control contains below script and it execute multiple times which is wrong.

```
$('checkbox').click (function() {.....});
```

I have not added ID properoty of checkbox as it is one control of user control and user control can be added any times on single aspx page.

Please suggest how i could assign one unique ID to the checkbox dynamically OR what shuld be selector to register this click event.

addition:

```
User control contains -----<checkbox> and other controls and script as shown above.
```

Now, dynamically ASPX page loads the same user control mulitple times so, all the controls reside inside the user control appear multiple times and registered click event is not executed for particular checkbox (containg in a control). it execute two times as two user control added on one page.

Comment: How are you adding it to the page?  Would one event handler for all checkboxes work, rather than 1 for each?

Comment: First of all: I don't think that your `event` will be fired at all, please use `$(':checkbox')`, so, you have missed selector. Second one, it's better to add the same `class` for your dynamic `checkboxes` and then call `$('.yourClassName').click`

Comment: when i do $('.classname').click means, click event will execute for each user control's checkbox (as classname will be same) when i click for particular user control's checkbox. that is the problem.I need to keep event separete for each checkbox-usercontrol even added any time on single page.

Comment: `when i do $('.classname').click means, click event will execute for each user control's checkbox`. That's NOT true. Yes, it REGISTERS a click-handler for all elements with `.classname`, but only the handler of the element clicked is fired. Simply test this with a `console.log("bla")` in your eventhandler: you'll see it will only be executed once per click. Moreover `this` inside the eventhandler will refer to the element clicked.

Comment: Emmm, didn't get! You should probably rephrase your question then. If you have `$('.yourCheckboxClassName').click(function(){ alert($(this).is(':checked')); });` So `this` means your **current/specific** clicked checkbox and it will be fired only once, if you click on some other checkbox with the same class it will be fired again but for that specific/clicked checkbox

Answer (score 0):

While creating the checkboxes, you can assign them classes. then you can use delegate for catching events

```
$(document).on("click",".classname",function(){
alert(this.checked);
});
```

Comment: checkbox is included into the user control. so, same CSS/CLASSname will be replicate for checkbox cntaing into multiple user controls on same page.